# Elementor icons showing squares

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am a newbie with wordpress. I have to fix some problems with the company webpage but when I logged in I realised that everything related with Elementor is not showing the icons (just those little squares shown bellow). I wonder what is the problem. I've follow some instructions of replacing urls but nothing has worked so far. If anyone has any hint I will be very grateful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it may due to slow internet and in some cases, it resolves by cleaning the browser cache.

Comment: @Coder1 thank you for your quick answer. I've already cleaned the browser cache and even tried in different browsers. And also different internet (home and work). Still the same problem

Comment: To catch the actual problem requires debugging. Alternatively, WordPress fresh install might fix this issue.